# Full Blockchain Solidity course Lesson 7: unknown function or type 'gasleft'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, solidity, chainlink, brownie

the function below is throwing an "unknow function or type error" when calling gasleft() and (bool success) is not being read.

```
    function callBackWithRandomness(
        bytes32 requestId,
        uint256 randomness,
        address consumerContract
    ) public {
        VRFConsumerBase v;
        bytes memory resp = abi.encodeWithSelector(v.rawFulfillRandomness.selector, requestId, randomness);
        uint256 b = 206000;
        require(gasleft() >= b, "not enough gas for consumer");
        (bool success,) = consumerContract.call(resp);
    }
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi [DorianDaSilva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18862548/doriandasilva)

Can you confirm that you've followed the addenda/udpates from this [README](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-py/blob/main/chronological-issues-from-video.md#lesson-7) regarding Lesson 7?  Specifically, that you're using a VRF V1 contract address?

Comment: Yes I am using the Rinkeby VRF Coordinator in my brownie-config and a modified consumerBase.sol v8.0 since the v6.0 wasn't working and v8.0 was returning an error at fulfillrandomness. I can share the full consumerBase.sol (Flattened - Impossible to import from chainlink github repo) and VRFCoordinatorMock.sol version that I am using if you want to look at it. It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Dorian - just wanted to confirm that you're using Coordinator V1 not V2 right?  Your answer does not clearly answer that.

Comment: I am at the testing stage....This is for the VRFCoordinatorMock calling a modified VRFConsumerBase.sol were I replaced rawFulfillRandomness with fulfillRandomness in order to fix the error I was getting on the last line of the contract. every contract and code prior to the testing phase of the lesson compiles and runs perfectly but yes, it should be VRFCoordinator V1  since V2 calls "randomWords". I can share the code if you want to look into it further. I thought maybe replacing gasLeft() with a web3 function to call gas left but not sure which one yet. Do thing this could work?

Comment: `gasLeft()` is a solidity globally available property ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.21/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties)] so is probably not causing the error.

Cant diagnose this with the info provided.  Manually replacing `rawFulfillRandomness` is not ideal because `VRFConsumerBase` specifies that that func is called externally by the Coordinator. also the code in your original post is from the mock for V1 which works as intended.

I feel there is something going on with your datatypes but hard to diagnose with available information!

Comment: Thank you for the input. I decided to drop the code and start from scratch following along the new version of the course but now I am running into some serious compiler issues as described here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72560937/lesson-7-compiler-version-error-1043-16-full-blockchain-solidity-course