# Lesson 7: Compiler Version Error -> 10:43.16 (Full blockchain solidity course)

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink, hardhat

```
$ /home/ionmind/hardhat-fundme-fcc/node_modules/.bin/hardhat deploy --network rinkeby
Error HH606: The project cannot be compiled, see reasons below.

These files import other files that use a different and incompatible version of Solidity:

  * contracts/test/MockV3Aggregator.sol (^0.8.12) imports @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/tests/MockV3Aggregator.sol (^0.6.0)

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose

Read about compiler configuration at https://hardhat.org/config
```

After getting this error I modified the hardhat.config.js file as instructed on the video

```
module.exports = {
  //solidity: "0.8.12",
  solidity: {
    compilers: [{ version: "0.8.12" }, { version: "0.6.0" }],
  },
```

But still getting the error, so I also modified the compiler version in solhint.js file

```
{
  "extends": "solhint:recommended",
  "rules": {
    "compiler-version": ["error", "^0.8.12", "^0.6.0"],
    "func-visibility": ["warn", { "ignoreConstructors": true }],
    "var-name-mixedcase": "off",
    "avoid-low-level-calls": "off"
  }
}
```

But still getting the error.

I created a separate AggregatorV2V3Interface file in test folder, locally imported into MockV3Aggregator.sol & also declared solidity version ^0.8.12 for each of the files

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

interface AggregatorInterface {
        //Code Here//
}

interface AggregatorV3Interface {
       //Code Here//
}

interface AggregatorV2V3Interface is AggregatorInterface, AggregatorV3Interface {}
```

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

import "./AggregatorV2V3Interface.sol";
```

There are no errors or warnings in the code but I still get the same error when trying to compile. I don't get why I seem to be the only person having this compiler issue.Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: AggregatorV3Interface import in fundme.sol & priceConverter.sol was causing the error so I had to create a new file in contracts and remove the ^ from the solidity version in hardhat.config & solhin.json. Now it compiles perfectly!

Comment: Do not add "[Solved]" to your question title. Also, post that comment below as a proper answer, not in the comment section.

Comment: Could you add this to the github repo? Mentioning a specific question from a video isn't great for stackoverflow. https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-js/

Answer (score 1):

Update your solidity versions:

```js
module.exports = {
  //solidity: "0.8.12",
  solidity: {
    compilers: [{ version: "0.8.12" }, { version: "0.6.6" }],
  },
```

Comment: I did update it to versions 0.8.12 & versions 0.6.0/0.6.6/0.8.0/0.8.8 but didn't work. I went around the issue by creating a MockV3Aggregator file inside test folder along wit AggregatorV2V3Interface and AggregatorV3Interface declaring v0.8.12 and removed the ^ from versions in file and in config file. This worked but now I am getting the following error when deploying. ```Error: expected 0 constructor arguments, got 2```

Comment: Can you please add your answer to your question below, and then make a new question for your new issue? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @patrick-collins, than you for the comment. I already solved it and moved forward with the course but now got ban from posting here since 3 people didn't underestand one of the questions and got me banned (Cancel culture in full effect) so no more stack overflow for me...See you on GitHub

Comment: No worries! Stackoverflow can be a little... upsetting. Please don't let this stop you from continuing to learn. Stack exchange Eth can be a little more forgiving too!